# python requests sslL Client hello uses TLS V1 and server refuses connection, and I don't know why it uses v1

Tags: python, python-requests, openssl, tls1.2

Context:
This is python 3.11.6 based on this docker image: python:3.11.6-slim-bullseye

Ultimately this is used for a zeep connection but the problem is the SSL connection is not established.

It is an up to date openssl library

```
print(ssl.OPENSSL_VERSION)
PyDev console: starting.
OpenSSL 1.1.1w  11 Sep 2023
```

I have this test script:

```
def test_connection(db_no_rollback):
    
    HTTPConnection.debuglevel = 1

    # Initialize a logger
    logging.basicConfig()
    logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    requests_log = logging.getLogger("requests.packages.urllib3")
    requests_log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    requests_log.propagate = True
    import ssl, socket

    hostname = 'www.handlingandfulfilment.co.uk'
    # hostname = "www.growthpath.com.au"
    # context = ssl.create_default_context()
    context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLS)  # create default context
    context.options |= ssl.OP_NO_TLSv1 | ssl.OP_NO_TLSv1_1  # disable TLS 1.0 and 1.1

    with socket.create_connection((hostname, 443)) as sock:
        with context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=hostname) as ssock:
            print(ssock.getpeercert())

    assert True
```

with most hostnames, wireshark shows a line like this:

```
6412    410.231952331   192.168.41.11   188.166.227.141 TLSv1.3 583 Client Hello
```

which makes sense to me, TLSv1.3

but with the problem server, I get this:

```
421 9.896938114 192.168.41.11   193.109.12.6    TLSv1   571 Client Hello
```

the source address (192.168.41.11) is my dev machine.
So my python code is sending hello with TLSv1

This leads to an exception:

```
self = <ssl.SSLSocket [closed] fd=-1, family=2, type=1, proto=6>, block = False

    @_sslcopydoc
    def do_handshake(self, block=False):
        self._check_connected()
        timeout = self.gettimeout()
        try:
            if timeout == 0.0 and block:
                self.settimeout(None)
>           self._sslobj.do_handshake()
E           ConnectionResetError: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer
```

which I am certain is because the server refuses TLSv1
Also, the administrators of the server are blaming my attempt at connecting with this version.

Why would this code be attempting to negotiate TLSv1?

Production which is a kubernetes deployment of that image has the same problem, so it is not anything idiosyncratic about my machine or office network.

## update

I have found a way of making it work by guesswork with chatgpt helping a bit, and I don't know why it works. And it is complicated.

after doing this to make sure 'pure' openssl works:

```
openssl s_client -connect www.handlingandfulfilment.co.uk:8079
```

I get a v1.2 connection and a cipher

```
New, TLSv1.2, Cipher is AES256-GCM-SHA384
```

this matches to

context.set_ciphers('ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES256-GCM-SHA384:!aNULL:!MD5')

but this fails with an unknown certificate. certifi can fix that.

I got to this, the assert is True

```
 # try a different way

    # Create a socket
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    sock.connect((hostname, 443))

    context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLS_CLIENT)

    import certifi
    context.load_verify_locations(certifi.where())
    context.set_ciphers('ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES256-GCM-SHA384:!aNULL:!MD5')

    wrappedSocket = context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=hostname)

    assert wrappedSocket
```

Answer (score 0):

The server at the other end is a Microsoft server. I can not find anything unusual about my use of python 3.11 and their end they are using a mainstream server certificate. Maybe they have unorthodox security settings.

To fix:

Step 1:
I did this to test the connection:

```
openssl s_client -connect www.handlingandfulfilment.co.uk:8079
```

this worked, and the output mentions a cipher in use.

> New, TLSv1.2, Cipher is AES256-GCM-SHA384

I used chatgpt to give me the correct cipher string matching that, and it responded

context.set_ciphers('ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES256-GCM-SHA384:!aNULL:!MD5')

This produced a new error involving certificates, so I used certifi.

This code to make the working zeep connection looks this this (I might not have got all the imports):

```
import certifi
# debugging aid
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
from urllib3 import PoolManager
from zeep import Client
from zeep.transports import Transport
import requests
from requests.adapters import HTTPAdapter, Retry
from urllib3.util.ssl_ import create_urllib3_context

CIPHERS = 'ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES256-GCM-SHA384:!aNULL:!MD5'


class TLSAdapter(HTTPAdapter):
    def init_poolmanager(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = create_urllib3_context(ciphers=CIPHERS)
        # Load the certifi certificates
        context.load_verify_locations(certifi.where())
        context.set_ciphers(CIPHERS)
        context.options |= 0x80000  # SSL_OP_NO_TLSv1
        context.options |= 0x1000000  # SSL_OP_NO_TLSv1_1
        self.poolmanager = PoolManager(*args, ssl_context=context, **kwargs)


def requests_retry_session(
        retries=8,
        backoff_factor=0.3,
        status_forcelist=(500, 502, 503, 504),
        session=None,
) -> requests.Session:
    session = session or requests.Session()
    retry = Retry(
        total=retries,
        read=retries,
        connect=retries,
        backoff_factor=backoff_factor,
        status_forcelist=status_forcelist,
    )
    adapter = TLSAdapter(max_retries=retry)

    session.mount('http://', adapter)
    session.mount('https://', adapter)
    return session


class API_error(Exception):
    pass


@dataclass(order=True)
class ArkH:
    wsdl_url: str
    consumerName: str
    passCode: str
    helixClientName: str
    helixUsername: str
    userPassword: str
    client: Client = field(init=False)
    dummyCustomer: str
    dummy_customer_mapping = {'CTS':'CTS'} #map a Dear customer, fall back to dummyCustomer
    dear_warehouse:str
    dear_ship_after_3PL_shipment_date:bool

    def __post_init__(self):
        session = requests_retry_session()
        transport = Transport(session=session,timeout=40,operation_timeout=40)

        self.client = Client(self.wsdl_url,transport=transport)
```